# My laptop (details below) does not have use of the FN control keys and does not sleep - how could I debug/fix this

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 19.10, function-keys

I purchased a new laptop recently (Lenovo Yoga S740, i5 1035G4, Iris Plus Graphics, AX201 Wifi) and tried to install Ubuntu 19.10 onto it.

However, I noticed that it doesn't appear to have any FN controls (e.g controlling the screen brightness with the keyboard) or the ability to sleep (pressing the power button doesn't work).

Has anybody got any suggestions as to how I could go about solving this problem (I use my laptop for programming and Linux is a necessity for me).

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo's support page suggests:

Access the BIOS (method to enter BIOS in Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1, Windows 10).
Once in the BIOS menu, select the Configuration tab.
Select Hotkey Mode and set to Disabled.
Save and Exit the BIOS menu (press F10 and then Enter).

They also [list the defaults](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series/List-of-FN-Function-Key-features/ta-p/700841) for their function keys.

Comment: That mode is already enabled on my laptop. However, the function keys still don't perform as expected (pressing FN+the shortcut key doesn't do anything). I read online it could be an ACPI issue and was wondering if there was a way to verify this